# Wave propagation with a complex coefficient $\beta$ in a Robin boundary condition. How does this affect scattering from the boundary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, electromagnetism

Can anyone give me an idea of what happens in the following situation involving Robin boundary conditions with a complex coefficient.

Lets say we have an incident electromagnetic plane wave $u(x) = e^{i d \cdot x}$ in two dimensions, where $d$ denotes the incident direction, governed by the Helmholtz equation

$$\nabla u + k^2 u = 0,$$
in the upper half space $\mathbb{R}_+^2 = \{x: x_2 > 0\}$ with Robin boundary conditions on the boundary $\partial \mathbb{R}_+^2 = \{x: x_2= 0\}$. The Robin boundary conditions are

$$u + \beta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0,$$

where $\nu$ denotes the normal derivative in the positive $x_2$ direction. Now $\beta$ can be complex and this leads me to believe this boundary condition can be considered lossy and can increase absorption?

I am interested in what kind of happens to the waves when we let $|\beta|$ be very small and then increase it so that $|\beta|$ becomes very large. Can anyone explain how this will affect the scattering/reflection of the incident wave?

Comment: Is $u(x,y)$ a scalar field?

Comment: Yes it is, its the scalar Helmholtz reduction for Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **NOTE:  Herein, we use the time convention $\displaystyle e^{i\omega t}$**

If $u(x,y)=Ae^{-i(k_1x_1+k_2x_2)}+Be^{-i(k_1x_1-k_2y_2 )}$, then on the boundary we have

$$A+B+\beta(A(-ik_2)-B(-ik_2))=0$$

whence we have

$$\begin{align}
B&=-\frac{1-ik_2\beta}{1+ik_2\beta}A\\\\
&=-\left(\frac{\left(1+k_2\text{Im}(\beta)\right)-i\left(k_2\text{Re}(\beta)\right)}{\left(1-k_2\text{Im}(\beta)\right)+i\left(k_2\text{Re}(\beta)\right)}\right)\,A
\end{align}$$

When $\beta =0$, $B=-A$ and as $\beta \to \infty$, $B\to A$.

---

Note that if $k_2$ is a real number with $k_2\le 0$, then it is easy to see that $\text{Im}(\beta)\ge 0$ in order to ensure that $|B|\le|A|$.

---

Note that when $k_2=-i/\beta$, $B=0$ and the incident wave is fully absorbed.  Since we assume that $k_2\in \mathbb{R}$, this can only happen if $\text{Re}(\beta)=0$.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what $B = -A$ when $\beta = 0$ and $B \to A$  for $\beta \to \infty$ imply with regards to reflections? I don't see how this explains the boundary condition 'absorbing' waves?

Comment: This seems to be a statement about amplitudes, it doesn't seem to do anything for the direction of the wave such as blocking outgoing waves. The first 'B' term in your post represents a wave incoming from infinity in the upper half space and the 'A' term represents an outgoing reflection. But as $\beta \to \infty$ and get $B \to A$ both waves will now have the same amplitude/phase but the directions haven't changed..Wave B will still be incoming and wave A will still be outgoing!

Comment: First, the convention here is $e^{i\omega t}$ and so $A$ is the incident wave's amplitude. Is there any part of the analysis that you don't understand?  We are analyzing in $\vec k$-space, which is the 2-D Fourier Transform representation.  The amplitudes depend on $\vec k$.  When $k_2=-i\beta$ the wave is fully absorbed since $B(k_2)=0$ then.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I was extremely busy recently with end of semester work. When $k_2 = -i\beta$ we have $$B(k_2) = -\frac{1 - i(-i\beta)\beta}{1 + i(-i\beta)\beta}A = -\frac{1 - \beta^2}{1 + \beta^2}A$$. How are you getting $B(k_2) = B(-i\beta) = 0?$

Comment: Ah I see now, that was just a typo and you have $-i/\beta$ in the answer. That's great, I see how it works now! ...one last thing, with $\beta = 0$ we have Dirichlet boundary conditions and the wave reflect, with $\beta = ik_2$ we have full absorption of the wave...but what is happening physically when $|\beta| \to \infty$? This implies $B \to A$ in your post, what is physically happening with the wave in this case?

Comment: First, thank you for both the best vote and up vote!  Second, when $\beta \to \infty$, we have the Neumann Boundary Condition since $$u+\beta\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0\implies \frac1\beta u +\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0$$Now, letting $\beta \to \infty$ renders the boundary condition $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0$$Lastly, Happy Holidays!  -Mark